# How to calculate a combinatorial sum

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, combinatorial-proofs

I have a combinatorial sum in hand which I suspect equals zero. But I do not know how to prove it. Can you guys help me? (I am even not sure if this is a hard question or not)

Is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k k^{n-1} \left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
k
\end{array}\right) = 0
$$
?

Comment: Yes, this is true. It follows from taking finite differences.

Comment: Good to know it is so easy, could I ask for any more details (like a webpage where they have examples?) Thanks!

Comment: Following the clue given by @QiaochuYuan, I found the answer presented as Identity 17 in Combinatorial sums and finite differences by Michael Z. Spivey (2007).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k k^{n-1} {n\choose k}
= (n-1)! [z^{n-1}] \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \exp(kz) {n\choose k}
\\ = (n-1)! [z^{n-1}] (1-\exp(z))^n.$$

Now $$1-\exp(z) = -z - z^2/2 - \cdots$$ and hence $(1-\exp(z))^n = (-1)^n z^n + \cdots$ so that

$$(n-1)! [z^{n-1}] (1-\exp(z))^n = 0.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May I ask what doe the bracket sign in the first line mean?

Comment: This is a [coefficient extractor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Extracting_coefficients).

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:** Start with $$f(x)=(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^k.$$ Differentiate to show that $f'(-1)=0$. Differentiate again to show that $f''(-1)=0$. Keep going (inductively) until the $(n-1)$-th derivative.

Comment: I cannot get the quantity of interest following this answer, can you guys help me with it?

Comment: I think the quantity inside the summation should be $-exp(kx)$ rather than $x^k$?

Comment: Nope this is good as is. The point is that on the $(n-1)$-th deriviative, the LHS is still $0$ at $x=-1$, and your sum will look like $\sum\binom{n}{k}p(k)x^{k-n+1}$, where $p(k)=k(k-1)\dots (k-n+1)$ is some degree $n-1$ polynomial. From induction, you know that summing the $k^\ell$ terms at $x=-1$ gives $0$, for each $1\leq\ell\leq n-2$, so summing just the $k^{n-1}$ terms should also give $0$.

Comment: I see! Thank you for claraification~

Answer (score 3):

For a combinatorial proof, note that both sides count the number of surjections of an $(n-1)$-set onto an $n$-set. The RHS is obvious, and the LHS is the inclusion-exclusion formula, where the $n$ properties to be avoided are that $i$ is not in the image of the function. More generally, this proof shows that the identity holds if you replace the power $n-1$ with any number $<n$.