# Show $S_n=-nS_{n-1}+n\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}k^{n-1},\quad n\ge1$

Tags: proof-explanation, combinations, combinatorial-proofs

I'm stuck in this question. It seems so easy, but I can't see it and at this point I spent too many time on it to be able to look at it with fresh eyes.

For each $n\in N$, consider:
$$S_n=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}k^n$$

Show:
$$S_n=-nS_{n-1}+n\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}k^{n-1},\quad   n\ge1$$

Please help me get out of this misery. Appreciate any help.

edit: I've tried Pascal Rule but that didn't get me anywhere. I can't really understand what to do about the "$k^{n-1}$" part. I had a prior exercise where I had to prove a simpler version of this sum by mathematical induction, and it was fairly easy so I'm pretty sure this one is too. I just think I'm not being able to grasp it or probably I'm completely unaware of the principle to apply in this question.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far could you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: Note that the second sum is $0$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3984436/how-to-calculate-a-combinatorial-sum

Answer (score 3):

We have for

$$S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k {n\choose k} k^n$$

that it is

$$n! [z^n] \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k {n\choose k} \exp(kz)
= n! [z^n] (1-\exp(z))^n.$$

Observe that with $1-\exp(z) = - z - \cdots$ we have $(1-\exp(z))^n =
(-1)^n z^n + \cdots$ so that $S_n = n! \times (-1)^n.$

We also have for

$$T_n = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k {n\choose k} k^{n-1}
\\ = (n-1)! [z^{n-1}]
\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k {n\choose k} \exp(kz)
= (n-1)! [z^{n-1}] (1-\exp(z))^n.$$

Again using
$(1-\exp(z))^n = (-1)^n z^n + \cdots$ we find that $T_n=0$
as pointed out in the comments.

Thus the claim becomes

$$n ! \times (-1)^n =
- n \times (n-1)! \times (-1)^{n-1}$$

and we have the result.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer.

I have a few questions. What method did you use to get there ? I don't understand what you did there in the first step with the "$n![zn]$" nor what you mean by "exp". I'm afraid those are methods that I haven't learn yet, so if you can name them or something so I can some research to try and learn so I can comprehend the solution you offered. Thanks again

Comment: These are coefficient extractors from [formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Extracting_coefficients). The exponential $\exp(z)$ is $e^z.$ Once you've mastered coefficient extraction the rest should be straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

The first term $(k=0)$ in $S_n$ vanishes, so

$$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\binom nk k^n$$

and so

$$S_{n-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(-1)^k\binom {n-1}k k^{n-1}$$

Notice that

$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\binom nk k^n=\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k \binom{n-1}{k-1} n k^{n-1}$$

because

$$\binom nk k^n=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}k^n=\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!((n-1)-(k-1))!}nk^{n-1}=\binom{n-1}{k-1}nk^{n-1}$$

Then

$$\begin{align}
S_n+nS_{n-1}&=\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k \binom{n-1}{k-1} n k^{n-1} + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(-1)^k\binom {n-1}k n k^{n-1}
\end{align}$$

In the second sum, if $k=n$, then $\binom{n-1}k=\binom{n-1}n=0$, so we can have both sums over $1\le k\le n$ (or $0\le k\le n$), and the binomial coefficients condense due to [Pascal's identity](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Pascal%27s_Identity) to give the expected result.

$$S_n+nS_{n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom nk nk^{n-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(n-k)^m$$
is the inclusion-exclusion formula for surjections from an $m$-set to an $n$-set.  In particular, taking $m=n-1$ yields no surjections, so
$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}k^{n-1} = (-1)^n \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(n-k)^{n-1} = 0, \tag1$$
Similarly,
$$(-1)^n S_n =\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}k^n = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(n-k)^n = n!$$
and
$$(-1)^{n-1} S_{n-1} = (n-1)!.$$
Hence
$$(-1)^n (S_n + n S_{n-1}) = (-1)^n S_n - n (-1)^{n-1} S_{n-1} = n! - n(n-1)! = 0. \tag2$$
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ yields $$S_n + n S_{n-1} = 0 = n \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(n-k)^{n-1}.$$